# libcurl get JSON string

Tags: json, string, get, libcurl

I'm sorry for my simple question but I'm new using libcurl.
    I have the following  code:

```
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mypage.com/index.php?DataSourceId=1");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Everything works fine, so when curl_easy_perform(curl) is executed I get the JSON
string in the console and I want to get this string in a variable.

Please anyone can help me ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You need to ask libcurl to write directly into your own memory buffer via the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` option.

Please refer to the [getinmemory](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html) example that precisely illustrates how to do that.